# Windows 7 in VMWare Player requires credentials to access the host machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, svn, vmware-player

I'm running Windows 10 64 bit pro, and have installed Windows 7 Pro 64 bit into VMWare Player v12.5.7. I have internet access from the VM, but when I try to access the host machine in Windows Explorer (via the Network node), I get asked for log-in credentials for the host machine.

The first time this happened, I checked the "Remember my credentials" checkbox, assuming that I wouldn't be asked again. However, I regularly get asked for the credentials again.

Any idea how I can persuade Windows 7 (VM) to remember the credentials?

In case it's relevant, I took all the defaults when setting up the VM, so it uses NAT and connects at power on. I also haven't done anything specific with the networking on the host machine (not having a clue about these things), so they will be whatever Windows set when it was installed. If here's anything else I should add here, please let me know as I don't know what's relevant.

Thanks

P.S. Apart from the irritation of having to enter them every time, I suspect that this might be the reason why I can't access the SVN server on the host machine. I built this VM to use an outdated version of Microsoft Visual Studio, with a whole load of supporting software I didn't want to install on my main machine. However, I can't access the SVN server from the VM, which defeats the whole idea. I'm wondering if the failure to connect to the SVN server would be solved if the VM knew how to log in to the host.

Comment: I doubt that this has anything to do with running in a VM.  You'd probably have the same behavior if you were using a physical machine.

Comment: @jamesdlin Not saying you're wrong, but I've never had this problem with any physical machine on the network. either way, how would I fix it?

Comment: This seems like a Windows issue, not a VMware issue. Windows has its own way of deciding whether or not to store login credentials, it's not up to VMWare.